# How to catch cloud functions onCall functions.https.HttpsError by Flutter with cloud_functions package

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Flutter cloud_functions package and Cloud functions. I want to catch functions.https.HttpsError by on CloudFunctionsException (Client side) I can't catch functions.https.HttpsError with Flutter no matter what I intentionally throw.

Is it impossible to catch functions.https.HttpsError throw by cloud functions package with CloudFunctionsException?

Help me.

### cloud functions

```
export const sampleFunctions = functions.region(REGION).https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!data.hoge) throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'some reason');
    return { response: data.fuga };
});
```

### dart

```
  Future<dynamic> sampleFunction() async {
    final _cloudFunctions = CloudFunctions(region: 'asia-northeast1');
    final _sampleFunctions = _cloudFunctions.getHttpsCallable(
      functionName: 'sampleFunctions',
    );

    try {
      final resp = await _sampleFunctions.call(<String, dynamic>{
        'fuga': 'fuga',
      });
      print(resp);
    } on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
      print(e.code);
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [call function implementation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_functions/latest/cloud_functions/HttpsCallable/call.html) in Dart docs. If you take a look on it `CloudFunctionsException` is thrown only when exception property `code == 'functionsError'`.

With `functions.https.HttpsError` you are code from the first parameter( `'failed-precondition'` in the example). Unfortunately HttpError has limited possible values of error codes and "functionsError" is not in the [list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#functionserrorcode).

So it seems that it will not work this way.

I hope it will help!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I read this document
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client

So Dart can't catch it in the way described in this document?

Comment: In my opinion, yes. But I would suggest to raise it to package publisher. On package page https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions there is link to "View/report issues" on Github or try Pull Request.